# Generate n random points (Lat Lng pairs) from a center of a polygon within its(the polygons) bounds

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet

I am working on plotting data with in a polygon (District) but I do not have exact coordinates for each of the data sources from that district.

I would like however, to be able to plot all the results from a district accurately with in the bounds of that district but randomly scattering the pins (Markers) all over the district.

Does leaflet have any utilities to help me achieve this? If not has any one ever found any way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the bounds of that polygon that represents a district, I would try to get the maximum rectangle that can fit inside that polygon (you can find algorithms for this online). Once you get that rectangle, you should have it's bottom left and upper right points. The coordinates of these two points are the minimal and maximum lng/lat pairs. In that lat/lng interval you should generate your random markers. This way you can always be certain that your markers will be in the appropriate district.